# Looking for specific contents in each of the cells in the column and delete the row in some cases

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to take the output of our scheduling software for a TV station and get rid of anything for given times.  Unfortunately the output of the scheduling software creates a text field for time, not a field that can be formatted to time.  I haven't done any real programming in over a decade and this is frustrating me.  Here's a sample of the first few rows of the sheet - every day of the month contains entries for each program from 6:00a to the next day at 5:30a.

[image]

The code I've got so far is:

```
Sub delete_extraneous()

Dim rng As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim m As Integer

m = 1
j = 3

Goto ActiveSheet.Cells(j, m)

With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

For m = 1 To lastRow
    If rng = "6:30a" Or "7:00a" Or "7:30a" Or "8:00a" Or "8:30a" Or "9:00a" Or "9:30a" Or "10:00a" Or "10:30a" Or "11:00a" Or "11:30a" Then
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
    End If
Next m

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a suggestion; record a macro to find & replace 'a's, then filter on the time range.
Copy and paste to a new location and delete the original data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't state what your specific issue is in the code, but I can tell you a few problems you have.

**1)** This is not valid syntax `Goto ActiveSheet.Cells(j, m)`. There is a `GoTo` statement in VBA, but only use when absolutely necessary. (this case does not require it).

**2)** Don't rely on `ActiveSheet`. Instead reference the selected worksheet you desire to work with directly.

**3)** You never actually define `rng` so it's meaningless and your code will always bypass range. Using `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules can help avoid this issue.

**4)** Using active cell is also dangerous and may produce unintended consequences. In your case it will delete the same cell over and over and over again since you never activate any other cell. It's not needed.

See this code below. It also checks for row deletion and loads into a range for one delete statement later (which will be faster than deleting line by line, and doesn't require backwards looping).

```
Option Explicit

Sub delete_extraneous()

    Dim mySheet As Worksheet
    Set mySheet = Worksheets("mySheet") 'replace as needed

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = mySheet.Cells(mySheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim m As Long

    For m = 1 To lastRow

        Select Case mySheet.Cells(m, 3).Value 'check each row against column C

            Case Is = "6:30a", "7:00a", "7:30a", "8:00a", "8:30a", "9:00a", "9:30a", "10:00a", "10:30a", "11:00a", "11:30a"

                Dim deleteRng As Range
                If deleteRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set deleteRng = mySheet.Cells(m, 3)
                Else
                    Set deleteRng = Union(deleteRng, mySheet.Cells(m, 3))
                End If

        End Select

    Next

    deleteRng.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, I've tried each of these three answers and all of them give me errors.  I'm trying to figure them out this morning

The answer from Scott hangs on the next to last line: deleteRng.EntireRow.Delete - Object variable or With block variable not set, however deleteRng was set as Range.

The answer from Jeeped - Expected: identified or bracketed expression on the third from last line containing just a period.  Not sure what the purpose of it is, but if I remove it nothing happens.

The last answer, using autofilter gives the Sub or Function not defined error at the 6th line for AutoFilter

Comment: It looks like there was an issue inherent in my spreadsheet.  I started with a fresh copy and the answer from Scott was the first one I ran and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: @TodPoirier - glad you got it working. Please mark any one of the three answers as answered (click the grey check mark on top left of answer) for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array of text-that-looks-like-time and match against it.

```
Sub delete_extraneous()
    dim tms as variant, lastRow as long

    tms = array("6:30a", "7:00a", "7:30a", "8:00a", "8:30a", "9:00a", "9:30a", _
                "10:00a", "10:30a", "11:00a", "11:30a")
    with activesheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

        For m = lastRow to 1 step-1
            If not iserror(application.match(.Cells(m, "C").value, tms, 0))  Then
                .rows(m).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
            End If
        Next m
        .
    end with
end sub
```

Comment: As a note, due to row deletions, should loop through rows backwards

Comment: Thanks for catching that @tigeravatar.

Comment: Great!  I knew there was a much better way to accomplish this than what I was starting out to do, but I don't have time to start re-learning all this the right way.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Autofilter():

```
Sub test()
    Dim hours As Variant
    hours = Array("6:30a", "7:00a", "7:30a", "8:00a", "8:30a", "9:00a", "9:30a", "10:00a", "10:30a", "11:00a", "11:30a")

    With Range("C1", Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=hours, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(1, 1).value, hours, 0))  Then .Rows(1).Delete
    End With
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```